# How can I know which specific private key is used for 1 ssh connection?

Tags: linux, ssh

I cannot find from my linux box in which file the private key is stored.
In below testing, my findings is , there is no `~/.ssh.config` file, nor `~/.ssh/id_dsa` or equivalent.

From the testing result, it seems some configuration is taking effect? But how can I found which file is it? I enabled the -v option in ssh connection as well, but nothing useful is found.

```
$ ls ~/.ssh
authorized_keys  authorized_keys.bak  known_hosts  known_hosts.bak

$ ls /etc/ssh/
moduli      sshd_config           ssh_host_dsa_key      ssh_host_ecdsa_key      ssh_host_ed25519_key      ssh_host_rsa_key      ssh_import_id
ssh_config  sshd_config.original  ssh_host_dsa_key.pub  ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub  ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub  ssh_host_rsa_key.pub



$ ssh  git@bitbucket.com   #successful!!!
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
logged in as xx.

$ ssh  bitbucket.com     #failed!!!
Permission denied (publickey).

$ ssh  localhost  #successful!!!
```

BTW, I enabled `-vv` option for `ssh`, and I can see that the key being used is xx@host1, but I still didn't see which file the key is fetched from.

```
$ ssh -vv github.com
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.113] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/xx/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xx/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xx/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xx/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xx/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xx/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xx/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-dss,ssh-rsa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/xx/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: xx@host1 (0x55a060a66440),
debug2: key: /home/xx/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/xx/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/xx/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/xx/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: xx@host1
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 46:18:4d:dd:54:70:93:0a:77:70:f4:19:7f:0d:39:be
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([192.30.253.113]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 32000 rmax 35000
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 88
Hi xx! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug2: channel 0: written 88 to efd 6
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to github.com closed.
Transferred: sent 3632, received 1800 bytes, in 0.8 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 4558.3, received 2259.1
debug1: Exit status 1
```

And the lines in /etc/ssh/ssh_config is as below, excluding comments:

```
$cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config | grep -v ^#




Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

Answer (score 2):

```
debug2: key: xx@host1 (0x55a060a66440),
```

This key is provided by the `ssh-agent`. Check `ssh-add -l`. It should also list this key. But it is not possible to find out where it is (or was) stored. Currently it exists only in the process memory.

Comment: Yes, `ssh-add -l` prints out the fingerprint of the private key being used.But `ssh-agent ` process is not running by checking "ps -ef".

Comment: It is fingerprint of public key. Ssh-agent interface can present also different desktop apps such as gnome-keeyring.

Answer (score 0):

To enable more verbosity, you can try `ssh -v -v` to connect. 
In `debug2` output you should see which keys are offered and used.

To generate a key for your current user, use `ssh-keygen`. For example:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

creates **4096** bit **RSA key** with correct permissions.

Comment: I enabled -vv , and i found the key being used is `xx@host1`, but where is it from?

Comment: Seems the user you are logged in is "xx". As default /home/xx/.ssh/ or (~/.ssh/)  is the directory where ssh keys are expected. You can change these settings in /etc/ssh/ssh_config.
If you are user xx and want to use another key for a specific host, you can write a ~/.ssh/config file to use different keys for different host connections.

Comment: The directory ~/.ssh/ doesn't contain the private key files nor ssh config files.  So where is the private key being used stored for now?

Comment: For some reason, is it possible that the key file is stored in your current directory? Have a look at /etc/ssh/ssh_config which defaults are configured.

Comment: The printout of /etc/ssh/ssh_config is appended to above post.